# How to change the text font size for a choiceset in bot adaptive card

Tags: c#, botframework, adaptive-cards

We have an adaptive card in our bot with two different columnsets - first columnset to provide the user with options to select and the second columnset for the user to select if he is not interested in selecting an option.

The issue is with adjusting the font size for the text in second columnset choice set. Is there any attribute I could use to adjust the size of text in this choiceset?

```
new ColumnSet()
{
    Columns = new List<Column>()
    {
        new Column()
        {
            Items = new List<CardElement>()
            {
                new ChoiceSet()
                {
                    Id = "FeedbackOptions",
                    Choices = FeedbackChoice,
                    Separation= SeparationStyle.Default,
                    IsMultiSelect =true,
                    Type ="Input.ChoiceSet",                                           
                    Style = ChoiceInputStyle.Expanded
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the schema exploration [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html) and [here](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.Choice.html), there are no available attributes for configuring the font size.